# What should I delete when "Failed to fetch ppa"

Tags: updates, ppa, launchpad

So when I tried to update I got the following message error:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/floe/libtisch/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

After I googled it I found this [page](http://blog.launchpad.net/ppa/failed-to-fetch-errors-for-ppas). In "/etc/apt/sources.list" I did not find anything, like what is said in the post. BUT when I looked in the "/etc/apt/sources.list.d" folder (as it suggested) I found these two files (among other ones) that are correlated with my error.

---

***File No 1:***

name: *floe-libtisch-trusty.list*

in the file I found:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/floe/libtisch/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/floe/libtisch/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/floe/libtisch/ubuntu trusty main
```

---

***File No 2:***
name: *floe-libtisch-trusty.list.save*

in the file I found:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/floe/libtisch/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/floe/libtisch/ubuntu trusty main
```

---

What I want to know is, should I delete this files? In the [post](http://blog.launchpad.net/ppa/failed-to-fetch-errors-for-ppas) is says to **not** delete lines that and with "main". What can I do??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the unwanted ppa delete the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/floe-libtisch-trusty.list`.

The other one is just a backup file, you can delete it too, but it will not matter.

That post you linked to is talking about modifying `/etc/apt/sources.list` and how to find lines to delete there (like "if the line ends with `main` it is one you want to keep), but that doesn't apply to the files in the subdirectory.